# RuleDeploymentException: Failed to access the default store for the user

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, exchange-server-2010

I nearly spent 3 Days to fix the issue which is related to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Email Router: Rule Deployment Wizard.

I installed Microsoft Exhange 2010 on same virtual box where CRM 2011 server is installed.

The problem
Rule Deployment Wizard is not able to verify/create/delete rules for selected user's mailbox. Always the ran into exception which is given below:

"Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ExchangeConnectorDeployment.RuleDeploymentException: Failed to access the default store for the user."

Any suggestion is highly appereciable.

Comment: did you check this KB? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545688

Comment: Yes I did, but still the problem persists! Thanks!